# Azure Toolkit for Eclipse "Sign In" button is not working

Tags: eclipse, azure, eclipse-plugin

Azure Toolkit for Eclipse: v.3.25.0
Eclipse: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers
JDK: 16

After successfully installing the package, Eclipse recognizes it, but the "Sign In" button does not work after pressing it. Even if I try to open Azure Explorer or Azure Code Samples, it doesn't react at all.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9UIR.png)

What's even weirder is that if you click Azure Explorer fast enough after Eclipse is starting, a window opens, but it doesn't help.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPv9Y.png)

Comment: Can you log in to the `portal.azure.com` website?

Comment: I am using JDK1.8 and successfully logged in. Can you change to JDK 1.8 and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Toolkit for Eclipse requires the following software components:

- Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, Mars, or later. You can download it at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/.
- A Java Developer Kit (JDK), version 1.7 or later.
- An operating system. The Azure Toolkit for Eclipse has been tested on the following operating systems:
  Windows 10, Windows 8 and 8.1, Windows 7
  Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2, Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2
  Mac OS X version “Yosemite” and later
  Ubuntu Linux version 14, 15, and 16

You can refer this [post](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-installation.md), it seems that JDK 1.6 is not supported by now.